# SwingWorker.process() not getting called in a command line application

Tags: java, multithreading, command-line, deadlock, swingworker

I have observed a strange behaviour of a command line application that invokes SwingWorkers. The code is non-optimal in the sense that it creates a lot of thread pools. However, due to the control of the `generation` variable, all these pools except the last one do not execute any code. It implies that threads from these pools not only do not participate in races for the locks, but should also be garbage collected and vanished.

A minimal working example (not making anything useful) is the following:

```
package test;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class Tester {

private final int threads;
private ExecutorService threadPool;
private final int size;
private long currGen;
private int left;
private int done;

public Tester(int size, int threads) {
    this.threads = threads;

    this.size = size;

    this.currGen = 0;

    this.left = size;
    this.done = 0;
}

private class TestWorker extends SwingWorker<Object, Object> {
    private final Tester tester;
    private final long generation;

    TestWorker(Tester tester, long generation) {
        this.tester = tester;
        this.generation = generation;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
        while(this.tester.get(generation)) {
            Thread.sleep(1);
            publish(1);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Object> results) {
        for(Object n : results) {
            this.tester.put(generation);
        }
    }
}

public void run() {      
    this.currGen++;        
    this.left = size;
    this.done = 0;

    System.out.printf("Starting %d\n", currGen);

    this.threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads + 4);

    for (int threadId = 0; threadId < threads; threadId++) {
        threadPool.submit(new TestWorker(this, currGen));
    }
}

public synchronized boolean get(long generation) {        
    if (generation != currGen) {
        return false;
    }

    if (this.left == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    this.left--;

    return true;
}

public synchronized void put(long generation) {           
    if (generation != currGen) {
        return;
    }

    this.done++;

    if (this.done == this.size) {
        this.run();
    }
}
}
```

Then, this class is run in the main method of my program by:

```
    Tester tester = new Tester(30 * 400, 30);

    tester.run();
```

**Observed behaviour:** The output consists of Starting 1\n [...] Starting 1034\n  After that the process is still alive, but no more lines are printed. The number of threads for my process is 31014 at the moment of deadlock. The experiment was carried out at a 24-cores machine.

**Expected behaviour:** The process should keep printing Starting k\n for k = 1, 2, ... forever or throw an `OutOfMemoryError` caused by too many ThreadPools created.

The presented example has limited debugging. At some moment I had more printf commands, they implied that the deadlock occurs when all the created threads of the current generation have called their `publish()` methods but the `process()` method is not called by the EDT.

Comment: What do you expect? When `this.done == this.size`, you are calling `run()`, which sets `done` to zero. A message is only printed when `this.done > this.size`, but this is obviously impossible to reach when you set `done` to zero before reaching that condition. I’m not sure whether you understood the purpose of thread pools when you are repeatedly creating new pools… But the purpose of this strange code is unclear anyway.

Comment: You print the  “Starting …” message right before creating a new thread pool so every time you see the message, you are creating a new thread pool with the fixed number of 15 threads. So when you see the message “Starting 2813” you have created 2813×15 == 42195 threads. And you think, you can really preclude a relationship between your program hanging and having created 42195 threads, all of them repeatedly calling `synchronized` methods on the same object?

Comment: Sorry, if that sounds too harsh, but the minimum requirement for a question is to describe the expected behavior and it is impossible to guess the intention from your program as it simply makes no sense at all. All threads are changing the same variables, so whether a thread completes or not, is purely random. And since every completion triggers the start of another 15 threads, you have simply created a variant of the infamous fork bomb.

Comment: I removed some of my last comments. I contradict myself by posting another attempt of explanation: you are assuming that by the time, a thread encounters the `this.done == this.size` condition, all others have finished. This is wrong. There will be one thread encountering the last item in `get`. By this time, no other thread has encountered `left == 0`. The thread will publish the last item. Now, 15 threads calling `get`, plus the EDT calling `put` compete for the lock.

Comment: Some might succeed and encounter `left == 0`, but surely not all. Now the EDT encounters `this.done == this.size` within `get()`, calls `run()`, starting 15 new threads *and* resets the very `left` variable to zero, that the threads not having completed yet will read in their next `get` call. All of them behave like new. Until one encounters the last item in `get` and the race starts again. Note that `synchronized` is “unfair”. The EDT trying to get the lock last, due to the `publish`/`process` relationship has a higher chance of getting the lock, leaving even more pool threads running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a discussion with Holger, the problem seems to be caused by creating multiple ThreadPool's:

After the program has executed for k rounds (i.e. it printed `Starting k\n`), there were k ThreadPools of size 34 created. Out of them, all threads except 30 executing the `doInBackground()` method from the last generation lastly do not execute any code, but still are `running`. The 30 threads that still execute code synchronise on `get()` and `put()` methods and fall in a deadlock, because AWT-eventdispatch thread for some reason does not execute `publish()` method. This deadlock is caused by the sole fact that there is a lot of threads created and `running` (even though most of them are not active and do not take part in the race).

The consensus after a discussion seems to be: because of creation of too many threads, the system (external to Java) violates some constrain and it makes JVM stop progressing.

Comment: You are looking into the wrong direction. If the EDT stopped calling `process()`, it can’t own the lock nor start more threads. That would imply that the other threads should proceed and eventually go into the waiting state or even terminate, once some of the pools are reclaimed by the garbage collector (it might depend on the Java version whether the pool has such a cleanup). It might be that the EDT hangs in the attempt of creating more threads for a new pool. That would be system dependent and outside the scope of the garbage collector. I admit, I haven’t tried your program with 24 cores…

Comment: I have modified the code in the first post to guarantee that the threads created in the successive generations do not race. The new code run for 1034 generations and reached a deadlock.

Do you see any explanation why, instead of any exception, I get a deadlock?

Comment: You are still creating new thread pools, even if you are now storing a reference to it into an instance variable. Either, use the same pool for all, e.g. `if(this.threadPool==null) { this.threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads + 4); }` or, if you insist on creating a new pool, trigger a shutdown of the old one: `if(this.threadPool!=null) { this.threadPool.shutdown(); } this.threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads + 4);` Note that `shutdown()` does not kill the threads; they will still complete their task(s) before terminating. This seems to be exactly what you want…

Comment: Holger, please focus. I agreed in one of the posts that having a global pool seems to solve the problem. I do not claim my code to be good, optimal, meaningful, or whatever. I just want to know **precisely** why it **deadlocks**. And none of the explanations is convincing.

Comment: As said, if you can’t live with a global pool, you can use a new one by shutting down the old one. Otherwise, you still have ten thousands of threads and are creating more. This will hit a system depend limit at some time. It’s outside Java, hence, you can’t expect Java to handle the situation and throwing an exception. I don’t see a deadlock, it’s rather a [livelock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deadlock#Livelock). With your new  code, my machine makes constant progress even after 2000 generations, 23k threads, but is getting slower and slower. Your system seems to have a different profile.

Comment: I can live with a global pool, I have just run my actual application with a global pool and a `shutdown()` method whenever the pool needs to be reset (i.e. its size changed). In this sense your suggestion to use global pool was useful and I thank you for it.

I wouldn't say that it is a livelock because e.g. cpu usage for the java process after the last Starting k\n was printed is 0.

I will add something to the reply in a moment.